# How to modify MenuButton arrow color by JavaFX not FXML CSS?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

i am trying to modify color of `MenuButton` arrow , using `JavaFX` code not by `CSS`.

i found it inside `caspian.css` :

```
.menu-button > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 -1 0, 0;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;
    -fx-padding: 0.25em; /* 3 */
    -fx-shape: "M 0 -3.5 v 7 l 4 -3.5 z";
}
```

i tried to use something like that :

```
menubutton.lookup(".arrow");
```

but it throw `NullPointerException`

and when i do that :

`System.out.println(this.getStyleClass().toString());`

it out put that only: `menu-button` only.

so can any one give me the way to modify it using Java without using CSS ??

Comment: Have you tried lookup with ".arrow"?

Comment: lol , sorry , that already what i tried , yes but it didn't work

Comment: When are you doing the lookup? Lookups will only work once css has been applied, which is typically after the menu has been displayed.

Comment: If the statement `menubutton.lookup("arrow")` **throws** `NullPointerException` it means that `menubutton` is `null`. It may be that you are executing this code **before** the FXML is loaded and stuff initialized. Can you show more code, in particular the place where this line is called?

Comment: @Jason4Ever, @James_D: I noticed that `lookup()` will indeed return the correct thing if called *after* `primaryStage.show()` (i.e. the answer from James_D), but it does return `null` if called before.

Comment: I guess the other point to make here is that lookups are inherently non-robust. The preferred way to do this is using CSS.

Comment: Or, of course, by changing the value of -fx-mark-color for the menuButton. Which I should have seen half and hour ago. Answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RedMenuButton extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        final MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton("Menu");
        menuButton.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem("Item 1"), new MenuItem("Item 2"), new MenuItem("Item 3"));
        root.getChildren().add(menuButton);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        menuButton.lookup(".arrow").setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Update: But this is a better solution (which I probably would have got first time if daylight savings hadn't messed with my sleep ;)).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RedMenuButton extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        final MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton("Menu");
        menuButton.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem("Item 1"), new MenuItem("Item 2"), new MenuItem("Item 3"));
        root.getChildren().add(menuButton);

        menuButton.setStyle("-fx-mark-color: red");

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

## There are several ways to do this, here are four. The code is Jython with JavaFX. You can edit this code to meet your needs.

---

> First, the enum, for context.

```
public enum URLBarArrowConstants {
     //URLBarArrow Constants
     BYCSS_AND_SHAPE,
     BYCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE,
     NOCSS_AND_SHAPE,
     NOCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE;
}
```

> Second, the css files, for context.

EG #1

```
/*ComboBox's Arrow is a Region.*/
.combo-box .arrow-button .arrow {
     -fx-shape: "...";
     -fx-scale-shape: true;
     -fx-position-shape: true;
}
```

EG#2

```
/*ComboBox's Arrow is a Region.*/
.combo-box .arrow-button .arrow {
    /*Setting either of these two will do.*/
     -fx-background-color: transparent; 
     -fx-opacity: 0.0;  
}

/*ComboBox's Arrow Button is a Stack Pane.*/
.combo-box .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-position: center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-image: url("..<file>.png");
}
```

---

> The method, in my main file.

```
def setCustomURLBarArrow(self, url_bar, scene, URLBarArrowConstant):
    from javafx.scene.paint import Paint
    from javafx.scene.shape import Shape, SVGPath, FillRule
```

### Don't configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS, instead, do it programmatically and change the Regions SVG Shape

```
if URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.NOCSS_AND_SHAPE:

    #SVG Object
    previous_url_bar = SVGPath()

    #SVG Path
    previous_url_bar.setContent("...") # edit this 

    #SVG Fill Rule
    previous_url_bar.setFillRule(FillRule.NON_ZERO)

    #Set Fill -- 
    previous_url_bar.setFill(Paint.valueOf(Color.web("...").toString())) //edit here

    #Apply CSS Sheet
    url_bar.applyCss()

    #Set Region's Shape
    arrow_region = url_bar.lookup(".arrow").setShape(previous_url_bar)
```

## Configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS and change the Regions SVG Shape

```
elif URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.BYCSS_AND_SHAPE:
    #Apply Stylesheet for URL Bar
    scene.getStylesheets().add(File("..<file>.css").toURI().toString()) //edit here
```

## Configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS but instead, merely hide the arrow by setting the transparency/opacity values and set a background.

```
elif URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.BYCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE:
    #Apply Stylesheet for URL Bar
    scene.getStylesheets().add(File("..<file>.css").toURI().toString()) //edit here
```

## Don't configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS, instead, do it programmatically and merely hide the arrow by setting the transparency/opacity values and set a background.

```
elif URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.NOCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE:

    from javafx.scene.paint import Paint
    from javafx.scene.layout import CornerRadii
    from javafx.scene.layout import Background, BackgroundSize, BackgroundImage, BackgroundPosition, BackgroundRepeat, BackgroundFill

    #Apply CSS Sheet
    url_bar.applyCss()

    #Grab Arrow(Region), ArrowButton(StackPane) ComboBox properties
    arrow_region = url_bar.lookup(".arrow")
    arrow_button = url_bar.lookup(".arrow-button")

    #Either Set Opacity to 0 or set background color to transparent.
    arrow_region.setOpacity(0.0)
    arrow_region.setBackground( Background( array(BackgroundFill, [BackgroundFill( Paint.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT.toString()), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)]) ) )

    #Set a Background Image for the .arrow-button StackPane.
    arrow_button.setBackground(Background( array(BackgroundImage, [BackgroundImage( Image( String(File('..<file>.png').toURI().toString()), True) , BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT)] ) ) )       //if you want, edit this
```